# SQL Query with a date and a sequence field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have imported the Retrosheet (play-by-play baseball database dating back from 1952) data into a MySQL database. There is a GAME_ID field identifying a baseball game.

```
First 3 fields: home team
Next 8 fields: YYYYMMDD
Last field: game sequence for double-headers, triple-headers.
```

ATL199206230 = Game in Atlanta played on June 23rd – First game of the double-header
ATL199206231 = Game in Atlanta played on June 23rd – Second game of the double-header

Because I needed the date for most of my queries, I created a GAME_DATE column and I parsed the GAME_ID field to update it. I also created a GAME_SEQ field for the sequence field.

Let’s say I want to query my table for all data with a game date lesser or equals to a game which is the first game of the double-header (ATL199206230).

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE GAME_DATE <= ‘1992-06-23’.
```

This doesn’t work because I don’t want to get the data from game “ATL199206231”.

How could I use the GAME_SEQ in my query?

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE GAME_DATE <= ‘1992-06-23’ and GAME_SEQ = 0
```

This wouldn’t work either because I would want this game
BOS199008231 (second game of a double-header in 1990)

I thought of including the GAME_SEQ field in the “time” part of the date.

Ex:

```
1992-06-23:00:00:00
1992-06-23:01:00:00
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: add "AND !(Game_Date = ‘1992-06-23’ AND GAME_SEQ = 1)"  This will eliminate only the second game from your max date value.  All other games, first or second on a given day, will come back in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE GAME_DATE <= ‘1992-06-23’ and GAME_SEQ = 
case when GAME_DATE  = ‘1992-06-23’  then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the games on that date, then use:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE GAME_DATE < '1992-06-23'
```

Or, perhaps you intend:

```
WHERE GAME_DATE < '1992-06-23' OR
      (GAME_DATE < '1992-06-23' AND GAME_SEQ = 0)
```

MySQL should do the right thing with:

```
WHERE (GAME_DATE, GAME_SEQ) <= ('1992-06-23', 0)
```